# Fetching html code after window.open

Tags: javascript, html

i'm trying to fetch html code of a window after a window is loaded with `window.open`

But it doesn't work actually. I guess the issue is about how i managed my onload function but i don't understand the problem here, nothing is displayed in my console.log (i have no error)

My html code :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ftp.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
        <title>FTPtoolJS</title>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor='#ffffff'>

    <p><table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='1'
              align='center' width='98%'>
        <form name=login>
            <tr><td align='right'>&nbsp;Username&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;<input type='text'
                                 name='username' value='username' size='20'
                                 maxlength='20'>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr><td align='right'>&nbsp;Password&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;<input type='text'
                                 name='password' value='**********' size='20'
                                  maxlength='20'>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr><td align='right'>&nbsp;Server&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;<input type='text'
                                 name='server' value='ftp.adresse.com' size='60'
                                 maxlength='120'>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr><td align='right'>&nbsp;Directory&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;<input type='text'
                                 name='directory' size='60'
                                 maxlength='200'>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr>
        </form>
    </table><hr>

    <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
        <tr>
            <td align='right'>
                <input style='color:#000000' type='button' value='Connect' onClick='Login(this.form)'>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

My JS code :

```
function Login(form) {
    var username = form.username.value;
    var password = form.password.value;
    var server = form.server.value;
    var directory = form.directory.value;

    if (username && password && server) {
        FTPConnect(username, password, server, directory);
    }
    else {
        alert("error");
    }
}

function FTPConnect(username, password, server, directory){
    var url;
    var w;

    if(directory != undefined){
        url = "ftp://" + username + ":" + password + "@" + server + "/" + directory;
        w = window.open("ftp://" + username + ":" + password + "@" + server + "/" + directory, '_blank',
            'toolbar=yes,location=yes,status=yes,' +
                'scrollbars=auto,copyhistory=no,menubar=no,width='
                + ((screen.AvailWidth/2)-12) + ',height='
                + (screen.AvailHeight-124) +',left=' + ((screen.AvailWidth/2))
                + '),top=0,resizable=yes');
    }
    else {
        url = "ftp://" + username + ":" + password + "@" + server;
        w = window.open("ftp://" + username + ":" + password + "@" + server, '_blank',
            'toolbar=yes,location=yes,status=yes,' +
                'scrollbars=auto,copyhistory=no,menubar=no,width='
                + ((screen.AvailWidth/2)-12) + ',height='
                + (screen.AvailHeight-124) +',left=' + ((screen.AvailWidth/2))
                + '),top=0,resizable=yes');
    }

    w.onload = function() {
        console.log(w.documentElement.outerHTML); //here nothing is displayed in console.log
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick glance at your code and the following sticks out

```
w = window.open("ftp://" + username + ":" + password + "@" + ...
```

This will **fail the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) test** because

1. The protocol doesn't match
2. It looks like `server` might be a different host, too

In this instance, you can't enable support through *CORS* either, because accessing a *Window* is a bit more strict than an *XMLHttpRequest* in that it won't look for permission headers.

---

It looks like username & password doesn't make origin test fail

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i understand the problem here, is it possible to manage what i want to do by using html FTP page ?

Comment: You'll need to be on the same domain, same protocol and same port :)